# Index exceeds matrix dimensions when finding max value

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to find the max value from an array. But I keep getting the following error. Please advise.

```
scores = [19212       56722       73336       44805       47268]

max(scores)

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you probably have a variable called `max`. Try

```
clear max
max(scores)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. Apparently i had some other variable "max" my workspace.

Answer (score 10):

Have you defined an array called **max** ?

```
scores = [19212       56722       73336       44805       47268 ]

max(scores)

ans = 73336
```

If I define an array called max

```
max=[1:10]

max(scores)

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Check by using the which function

```
which max

max is a variable.
```

It should be

```
which max

built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@logical\max)  % logical method
```

Comment: What does "built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@logical\max) % logical method " mean?

Comment: @theIronGiant : "Built-in" is short for "built-in function", as opposed to a variable, or possibly a function from a non-standard toolbox. The file path given is where you would find the implementation of MATLAB's `max()` function if you were curious enough to go looking.

Comment: The "built-in" bit indicates that it's a native MATLAB function, the path name just indicates where it's located, this one is version 2009a installed on a Windows machine, your setup may have a different version or location.

Comment: +1 to this answer because it explained the problem, how to fix it, and how to recognise it in future.

Comment: Yeah well explained. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

To get the indices of the maximal value:
    scores=1:10;
    find(scores == max(scores))

If you have two maximum values:

```
clear max
scores=10:-1:1;
scores=[scores 10];
find(scores == max(scores))

ans =

     1    11
```

As you might guess `max` return the `max` of an array:

```
>> max(scores)

ans =

    10
```